# Order ofQuery with AJAX PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

Got a bit of a confusing situation, I have a form on my webpage that allows a user to enter information into a database...

***Form***

```
<form id="insertbill">
     Total <input type="text" id="total" name="total" /><br />
     Bill name<input type="text" id="bill-name" name="bill-name" /><br />
     bill descriptiion <input type="text" id="bill-description" name="bill-description" /><br />
     bill colour<input type="text" id="bill-colour" name="bill-colour" />
     <input type="button" value="submit" onClick="insertBill();" />
</form>
```

This form then send the information via AJAX to my php which then inputs it into my DB

***AJAX***

```
function insertBill()
{
    $.post('insert_bill.php', $('#insertbill').serialize(), 
        function(data) {
        $('#bills').append(data);
    });
};
```

***PHP***

```
   $uid = $_SESSION['oauth_id'];       
   $bill = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['total']);
   $billname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['bill-name']);
   $billdescription = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['bill-description']);
   $billcolour  = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['bill-colour']);

    #Insert Record
    $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `outgoings` (user_id, bill, bill_name, bill_description, bill_colour ) VALUES ('$uid', '$bill', '$billname', '$billdescription', '$billcolour')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Once this is done, the data is then returned to the webpage, with another form that allows the user to update the record...

***Returned data/form***

```
Print "<tr>"; 
Print "<th>total:</th> <td>".$bill . "</td> ";
Print "<th>bill name:</th> <td>".$$billname . "</td> ";
Print "<th>bill deposit:</th> <td>".$billdescription . "</td> "; 
Print "<th>colour:</th> <td>". $billcolour . " </td></tr>"; 
echo "<th>edit:</th> <td>

<form id='bill-upd'>
        <input type='hidden' value='". $billname."' name='billid' id='billid''>
        Total <input type='text' id='total' name='total' /><br />
        Bill name<input type='text' id='bill-name' name='bill-name' /><br />
        bill descriptiion <input type='text' id='bill-description' name='bill-description' /><br />
        bill colour<input type='text' id='bill-colour' name='bill-colour' />
        <input type='button' value='submit' onClick='updateBill();' />
    </form>   
</td>";
```

My problem is that the returned form doesn't update, this is because I need to somehow find the id of the record that was inserted, place it into my form to be returned I think... I hope this isn't too confusing, but has anybody a better way of doing this without reloading the page?

Comment: In `insert_bill.php` you could return the last inserted id to your javascript and then provide this id in your form in a hidden input field.

Comment: The only thing is there are multiple records returned, so if they want to edit one, the last pulled id wouldn't correspond to that

Comment: I am not sure if I understand correctly, but you could return an javascript object where you could explicitely name the last id

Comment: you can return this in PHP `json_encode(array('id' => $id, 'text' => $text));` then in your callback javascript function you have `data.id` and `data.text` as values. I hope it is clear

Comment: what does `console.log(data)` show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's what what you could include on your, insert_bill.php, view page:

```
<script> 
   var json=<? 
       $arr=array($bill, $billname, $billdescription, $billcolour);
       echo json_encode($arr); ?>;

     $('tr td:nth-child(0)').html(json[0]);
     $('tr td:nth-child(1)').html(json[1]);
     $('tr td:nth-child(2)').html(json[2]);
     $('tr td:nth-child(3)').html(json[3]);

</script>
```

I guess the one outstanding issue is the "id" you says gets returned from your database. Can you explain a little further? Are their multiple forms on your insert_bill.php page? Regardless, you could put that `$id` into the array and feed it into and `html()` function like I did with the other variables.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the data from the database and then change, i imagine if you just need the id you must do.

in PHP
echo mysql_last_insert_id(); // so you get the last inserted id and "return" to the JS
In JS, inside the function data
You get the echo as a return and change the id
and then $("#billid").val(data)

I hope it help you